# how to iterate a code for all the tables in the HTML data?

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, html-table

This is the HTML data of a webpage I'm scraping and as you can see it has multiple tabes. (https://paste.pythondiscord.com/resaxivedo.py)

```py
This is my code:
with open("tabledata.html", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    outfile = open("table_data.csv", "w", newline='')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    tree = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")

    dates = tree.findAll(class_="date")
    list_of_dates = [date.text for date in dates]

    table_tag = tree.select("table")[0]
    tab_data = [[item.text for item in row_data.select("th,td")]
                for row_data in table_tag.select("tr")]
    writer.writerow(list_of_dates[0])
    for data in tab_data:
        print(' '.join(data))
        writer.writerow(data)
```

As you can see I'm selecting the table and date with [0].
How can make a loop so it can print data for all the tables in the HTML page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for table_tag in tree.select("table") :
    tab_data = [[item.text for item in row_data.select("th,td")]
                for row_data in table_tag.select("tr")]
    writer.writerow(list_of_dates[0])
    for data in tab_data:
        print(' '.join(data))
        writer.writerow(data)
```